# Jquery masked input not working in knockout foreach

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-inputmask

I prepared a setting page that specifies every day's hour of works start time and end time. 
I set Day's name, Start Time, End time to form with Knockout foreach. I masked all StartTime fields and EndTime fields with Jquery maskedinput.

But fields in foreach are not masked. The fields allows to input letters.

I try to mask a field out of foreach, it works correctly and not allow to input letters.


Can anyone help?

Comment: can you show how you did the input masking in foreach

Comment: I set class to fields like 'timeMasked' then I excute below code in body on load  '$(".timeMasked").mask("99:99")

Comment: can you show it ind http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: it's working fine i tested it check here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26474/ . anyway you can show your issue(if) it would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed mask library 'jquery.maskedinput.js' to 'jquery.mask.js'.
It works correctly

Thanks '#super cool'